# Walking around a cube to return to starting point

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a cube of side length $1$ unit and I am supposed to walk $6$ units in total, starting from one vertex of the cube. I can move from one vertex to only any other adjacent vertex through the edge of the cube. In *how many ways* can I start and end at the same vertex?

**My work**

Suppose I start from any one of the vertices. Then I have noted that one way to satisfy given constraints is by moving to any adjacent vertex and moving back to the origin a total of 3 times. This gives me 27 possible ways for this case.

I also think that it has something to do with how many edges of a face are traversed which determines if the condition can be satisfied. But I can not work out anything concrete.

However if I try to do some casework I immediately find that the number of cases are too many to count and hence I’m unable to conclude anything useful. Help is appreciated.

Comment: I think a good place to start is to label the vertices with binary numbers of length $3$, and start at the vertex $000$, in each of the three directions have that correspond to increasing one of the bits. Then figure out what a path is in this formulation and what it also means to end back at $000$. I haven't worked through all the details, but I'd imagine that this point of view might help solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! That seems quite helpful too.

Comment: @PM2Ring No it's not? A Hamiltonian circuit visits every vertex and goes through each vertex exactly once. The OP's circuit can go more than once through the same vertex, and will visit at most 6 vertices out of 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to count the number of paths reasonably quickly if you look at the number of ways of getting to each position after a given number of steps, summing the values from the previous step like this

[image]

giving at the end $61+61+61= 183$ possibilities for getting back to the start.  If that is too much effort then you can

- stop after three steps and then combine with the number of ways back: $7^2+7^2+7^2+6^2 = 183$ or
- spot (and then prove) the obvious pattern after an even number of steps: $\left\lceil\frac{3^6}{4}\right\rceil = 183$.

Comment: Is there an intuitive reason why this holds true? Why is it so that I can simply do that sum to obtain the required number of ways?

Comment: How which part holds true? An intuitive argument is you have $3$ choices at each step so $3^n$ after $n$ steps, and that that each of the four possible positions is roughly equally likely (three of them exactly equal) with a small bias towards points near the starting point and a small bias away from the opposite points, so $\frac{3^n}{4}$ rounded.

Answer (score 12):

As another way to see it, note that we can describe any path along the cube as a string of $X$'s, $Y$'s, and $Z$'s, where X means "change your $x$-coordinate from 0 to 1 or vice versa," and similarly for $Y$ and $Z$.  What's more, the string corresponding to any *closed* path along the edges of the cube will have an even number of $X$'s, $Y$'s, and $Z$'s.

So the cases are:

1. Strings with 6 identical symbols.  There are three such strings: $XXXXXX$, $YYYYYY$, and $ZZZZZZ$.
2. Strings with four symbols of one type and two of another.  For a given choice of the two types of symbol ($X$ and $Y$ respectively, say) there are $\frac{6!}{4! 2!} = 15$ such strings.  There are further 6 possible choices for the types of symbols in the string (noting that, for example, 4 $X$'s and 2 $Y$'s is distinct from 4 $Y$'s and 2 $X$'s.)  So we have $15 \times 6 = 90$ such strings.
3. Strings with two symbols of each type.  There are $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}=90$ such strings.

So all in all there are $3 + 90 + 90 = 183$ such strings and therefore 183 such paths on the cube.

Answer (score 3):

The number of walks of length $k$ from a vertex $i$ to a vertex $j$ in a graph can be obtained using the adjacency matrix of this graph, [by raising this matrix to power $k$ and looking at the content of cell (i, j)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Matrix_powers).

- Number the vertices of your cube 1-8. Build the adjacency matrix of your cube. It contains a 1 in cell (i,j) if and only if there is an edge from vertex i to vertex j; otherwise a 0.
- Raise this matrix to its 6th power; output the content of cell (1,1) (or any other diagonal cell - the graph is [vertex-transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph), so they should all be equal).

```
>>> import numpy as np

# adjacency matrix
>>> M = np.array([
... [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0],
... [1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
... [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
... [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],
... [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],   #   7---8
... [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],   # 3---4 |
... [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],   # | 5 | 6
... [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]    # 1---2
... ])


>>> np.linalg.matrix_power(M, 6)
array([[183,   0,   0, 182,   0, 182, 182,   0],
       [  0, 183, 182,   0, 182,   0,   0, 182],
       [  0, 182, 183,   0, 182,   0,   0, 182],
       [182,   0,   0, 183,   0, 182, 182,   0],
       [  0, 182, 182,   0, 183,   0,   0, 182],
       [182,   0,   0, 182,   0, 183, 182,   0],
       [182,   0,   0, 182,   0, 182, 183,   0],
       [  0, 182, 182,   0, 182,   0,   0, 183]])
```

**Final answer: 183.**

You might notice a lot of zeroes in matrix $M^6$: precisely 4 zeroes and 4 nonzeroes in each row and column. This is because the cube is a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), which means in particular that vertices that can be reached via a walk of odd length cannot also be reached by a walk of even length.